# columns not shown when binding to gridview using linq to sql with an empty datasource

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

Is there a way to display the columns of the data you are selecting from when binding to a datagrid with an empty datasource? Whenever I bind with an empty datasource, the grid won't even show.

```
var results = from t in db.vwTaskInfos where t.PriorityId ==  Convert.ToInt32(drdPriority.SelectedValue) select t;

         gvTasks.DataSource = results;
         gvTasks.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
         gvTasks.DataBind();
```

Comment: I relize I can just put text into the emptyDataText property of the gridview, but it would be nice if I could get the columns to show.

Comment: plz Show your gridview properties?

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = from t in db.vwTaskInfos where t.PriorityId ==  Convert.ToInt32(drdPriority.SelectedValue) select t;

         gvTasks.DataSource = results;
         gvTasks.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
         gvTasks.DataBind();
```

Change to:

```
var results = from t in db.vwTaskInfos where t.PriorityId ==  Convert.ToInt32(drdPriority.SelectedValue) select t;

         gvTasks.DataSource = results.ToList();
         gvTasks.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
         gvTasks.DataBind();
```

Notice I changed "gvTasks.DataSource = results;" to "gvTasks.DataSource = results.ToList();"

**EDIT:**

I see, your problem is not actually a linq to sql issue. It's a grid view issue. That being said, here is the solution you're looking for:

[GridView - Show headers on empty data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354369/gridview-show-headers-on-empty-data-source)

Comment: I tried this, and unfortunately when binding to an empty datasource, the gridview still comes up blank without any header.