# Show header of a empty Gridview for Datasource is List<Data>

Tags: asp.net, gridview, header

I am using a Gridview with datasource is a List. How can I show the header if the List is null or for a empty gridview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridView - Show headers on empty data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354369/gridview-show-headers-on-empty-data-source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [A more elegant solution to display GridView header and footer when the data source is empty](http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2008/01/30/a-more-elegant-solution-to-display-gridview-header-and-footer-when-the-data-source-is-empty.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

if you are using fx4.0 then Set ShowHeaderWhenEmpty to true in Grid view

please look at below code

```
asp:GridView ID="gvPreview" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HeaderTemplate property to setup the head programatically or use ListView instead if you are using .NET 3.5.

or

You can even try below

```
//if data exists

if (dtSource.Rows.Count != 0)
{
grdView.DataSource = dtSource;
grdView.DataBind();
}
else
{
 //Other wise add a emtpy "New Row" to the datatable and then hide it after binding.
 dtFunding.Rows.Add(dtSource.NewRow());
 grdView.DataSource = dtSource;
 grdView.DataBind();
 grdView.Rows[0].Visible = false;
}
```