# How to display no records found message in auto generated telerik gridview from datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, telerik-grid

I am dynamically creating `GridView` with `dataset` but getting problem when I have no Records in my `GridView` so in that case I want to show my `GridView` with all that columns with `No Records Found`.

This is my code but GridView is not visible:

```
 var table = new DataTable();
 table .Columns.Add("Source");
 table .Columns.Add("Destination");
 table .Columns.Add("Date");

If()
{
  //All my logics where i am generating value for this "Source,Destination,Date" Column.
  foreach (var item in data)
  {
     table.Rows.Add(Source,Destination,Date);
  }
  //Binding to Gridview
 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
 GridView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
   //No Records so display gridview with "No records" along with columns.
      GridView1.DataSource = dt; //Here i will not be having any data for this 3 columns Source,Destination,Date
      GridView1.DataBind();//But My gridview is not visible
}
```

**Aspx**:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                            <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="true" NoMasterRecordsText="No Records Found">
                                <Columns>
                                </Columns>
                            </MasterTableView>
                        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Edit you post and add `aspx` code for `gridview`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `NoMasterRecordsText` property for `MasterTableView` for gridview.

ASPX:

```
<MasterTableView NoMasterRecordsText="No Records Found" >
```

OR

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GridView1.MasterTableView.NoMasterRecordsText = "No Records Found";     
}
```

**EDIT: Binding data to GridView using OnNeedDataSource**

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="GridView1_NeedDataSource">
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="true" NoMasterRecordsText="No Records Found">
           <Columns>
           </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

**and in your code behind**

```
// GridView1_NeedDataSource
protected void GridView1_NeedDataSource(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    BindGridViewData();
}

//Bind Grid View 
private void BindGridViewData()
{
 var table = new DataTable();
         table .Columns.Add("Source");
         table .Columns.Add("Destination");
         table .Columns.Add("Date");

       if()
       {

         foreach (var item in data)
         {
            table.Rows.Add(Source,Destination,Date);
         }
         //Binding to Gridview
         GridView1.DataSource = dt;

      }
      else
      {

          GridView1.DataSource = dt; 

      }
}
```

Comment: see updated question but your solution is not working.grid disappears

Comment: @Learning You need to bind your data on `NeedDataSource` event of grid view. [Here's the link for more information](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-binding/understanding-data-binding/server-side-binding/advanced-data-binding-(using-needdatasource-event))

Comment: see this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800097/how-to-show-no-record-found-with-columns-in-gridview-asp-net

Comment: If you bind data to gridview in `NeedDataSource` event then you will get ` No Records Found` message in gridview

Comment: See i am very new to this asp.net so can you please update your ans with what you are saying but remember to use my dataset where i am defining my columns

Comment: now i want this to happen on my page load.how to call this on page load event?

Comment: can i ask you 1 question?

Comment: have you used linqtosql?

Comment: Yes But its better you ask another question with your concern. Its not the correct way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99102/discussion-between-learning-and-rahul-nikate).

Answer (score -1):

Gridview ASPX Page Put `EmptyDataText`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GvZone" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    EmptyDataText="No Records Found !"  >
 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: OP is asking for `telerik-gridview` and not for `asp-gridview`

Comment: I already said that i want my columns too.This is will display my columns.Please see my output